# Lloyd J. Austin III - pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

I pronounce "Lloyd J. Austin III" as "Lloyd J. Austin the third". Am I on the right track?

> Secretary of Defense **Lloyd J. Austin III**  tweeted:

> There is life changing work happening out here at the @FEMA vaccination site in Los Angeles. The story of one of our own, a young soldier from right here in L.A., who vaccinated his mother... that's going to stick with me for a while.

Comment: Roman numerals used as ordinals are pronounced like the English equivalent ordinal, thus 'the third' in your example. Queen Elizabeth II is pronounced 'Queen Elizabeth the second'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Michael Harvey commented,

> Roman numerals used as ordinals are pronounced like the English equivalent ordinal, thus 'the third' in your example. Queen Elizabeth II is pronounced 'Queen Elizabeth the second'

Henry VII would be pronounced as *Henry the Seventh*

Comment: Maybe worth noting that Edward I would have been known simply as "King Edward" during his lifetime (not "Edward the first").